# Odoo creating an invoice with Web Service API (PHP)

Tags: php, python, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to create an invoice on Odoo using Odoo Web Service API (via PHP) which is based on XML-RPC using the code example in the [official API documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html).  I have succeeded to create a customer using the code provided in the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html) :

```
$id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
    'res.partner', 'create',
    array(array('name'=>"New Partner"))
);
```

But I can't create an invoice using the code sample provided:

```
$client = $models->execute_kw(
    $db, $uid, $password,
    'res.partner', 'search_read',
    array(array(array('customer', '=', true))),
    array(
        'limit' => 1,
        'fields' => array(
            'property_account_receivable_id',
            'property_payment_term_id',
            'property_account_position_id'
        )))[0];
$invoice_id = $models->execute_kw(
    $db, $uid, $password,
    'account.invoice', 'create', array(array(
        'partner_id' => $client['id'],
        'account_id' => $client['property_account_receivable_id'][0],
        'invoice_line_ids' => array(array(0, false, array('name' => "AAA")))
    )));
```

when I run the code I get an error response:

```
array(2) {
  ["faultCode"]=>
  int(1)
  ["faultString"]=>
  string(989) "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 56, in xmlrpc_return
    result = odoo.http.dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 118, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 38, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 157, in execute_kw
    return execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 143, in wrapper
    raise ValidationError(msg)
ValidationError: ('The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:\n- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it\n- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set\n\n[object with reference: price_unit - price.unit]', None)
"
}
```

Though it creates the invoice if I change this line into an empty array:

```
'invoice_line_ids' => array(array(0, false, array('name' => "AAA")))
```

But then I don't know how to add the invoice lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For invoice lines(account.invoice.line) there are many required fields like name(description), qty etc.In your example you have passed only name.

Try passing all required fields.

Comment: Can you please provide me the required fields ? or a link to a documentation where i can find them ? Thanks!

Comment: Easy way is just print the vals in create method of account.invoice.line, And creating a sample invoice with all fields you need to fill.

Comment: I think the missing field may be account_id(if you have'nt specified a default debit and credit account to customer invoice journal, you will have to enter it with all invoice lines).

Comment: i specified the account_id as you can see in the account.invoice create. I also checked and it contains an ID.

Comment: There is a account_id field in invoice line not in invoice.

Comment: I created a bank account for the used customer but the peroblem persists. Thanks

Comment: Account_id is in invoice line is not related to customer, you can specify it in default debit/ credit account in customer invoices journal.

Comment: I don't find any link to create a default debit/ credit account in customer invoices. All i can see is create + import buttons. could it be related to low account privilege access for my account ? Thanks

Comment: it is in customer invoice journal not customer invoice

Comment: Do i have to do this setting by product/service ?

Comment: what do you mean by products/service?.It is in Accounting/ Configuration/ Accounting/ Journals.

Comment: I mean for each product entered, we have to set a default account ?

Comment: yes, if default value for customer invoice is not set

Comment: Thank you for your help. the account i use now doesn't have the privilege to create/update products. So i think that's what's causing the issue as i can't set a default account for each product.